# Unable to start aidl service : java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, aidl

When I try to start service of my AIDL app from clientapp, getting following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: rajusugale.dev.clientmodule, PID: 5873
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rajusugale.dev.clientmodule/rajusugale.dev.clientmodule.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=rajusugale.dev.myaidllibrary/.CoffeeMakerRemoteService } without permission not exported from uid 10096
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**Code:**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent()
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    "rajusugale.dev.myaidllibrary", "rajusugale.dev.myaidllibrary.CoffeeMakerRemoteService"));
    mLog.setText("Starting service…\n");
    startService(serviceIntent);
    mLog.append("Binding service…\n");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Source on Github:
https://github.com/RajuSE/aidl-remote-service

First I'm opening aidl app(which has process which can run service) and then running clientapp which tries to run this service remotely.

Please let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Make sure that your aidl client will be in the same package.

Comment: Yes all aidl files are in same package.. You can check the source..

Answer (score 1):

Based on error you are getting I think you forget to add  `android:exported="true"` in your manifest file inside service tag of your client app.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: This is useful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTxX5X3XxHE